# How does having a repeated root in $trigonometric$ $equations$ (non-polynomial) imply touching, but not crossing the $x$-axis?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, roots, graphing-functions

Consider

$$f(x)=cos\left(2x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)-cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0 \tag{1}$$
giving
$$2x+\frac{\pi}{3}=\pm\left(\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+2r\pi \tag{2}$$
$\pm \to +, r \to n$
$$x_n^+=\pi\left(\frac{24n-1}{6}\right) \tag{3}$$
$\pm \to -, r \to k$
$$x^-_k=\frac{\pi}{42}\left(24k-7\right) \tag{4}$$
where $r,n,k \subset Z$.

Then $x=...,-31\pi/42,-\pi/6,17\pi/42, 41\pi/42...,$

According to the textbook that I am reading, as $$x^+_{n=0}=x^-_{k=0}=-\frac{\pi}{6} \tag{5}$$ is a repeated root, $x=-\frac{\pi}{6}$ is a value at which the curve touches the $x-axis$ without crossing it.

But I do not understand how having a repeated root in trigonometric equations implies touching the $x$-axis (the notion of change of sign does not seem applicable here)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10408/polynomials-derivatives-and-repeated-roots

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee But this is for polynomials, not trig. equations isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any real function $y=f(x) $ whether algebraic or trigonometric, has a double root at $x=a$  if

$$ f(a)=0,\; f'(a)=0\;$$

For example there is a double root at

$x=-1$ for the curve (circle)

$$ (x+1)^2+(y+1)^2=1$$

where it touches x-axis.  A trig function
also has the same situation:

Quite the same happens for the following implicit trig function

$$ \sin x \sin (y-\frac14) = \frac14 $$

[image]

Any smooth function can be chosen  from trigonometric, hyperbolic algebraic polynomials functions to be eligible.They should have series expansion with continuous derivatives. You were perhaps first introduced to algebraic polynomials for ease of differentiation.

Comment: Thanks. I can see why this happens for algebraic/polynomial expressions. Is there a proof of this for the trigonometric case?

Comment: Did you seek a proof for algebraic/polynomial cases? Accept this also in that function  list.